# Prove this lie subgroup has finite center

Tags: matrices, lie-groups, lie-algebras, linear-groups, automorphism-group

Let $G$ be a connected lie group with finite center. Let $H<G$ be a connected lie subgroup with lie algebra $\mathfrak{h}<\mathfrak{g}$ isomorphic to $\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb{R})$. Prove that $H$ has finite center.

If required, you may assume $G$ is semisimple

My attempts:

I'm not quite sure how to go with it, but there are two facts I have found probably relevant:

1. I know that in general for connected groups, $\ker Ad_G=Z(G)$ and therefore $G/Z(G)=Ad_G(G)$.
2. Since $\mathfrak{h}=\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb{R})$, $Ad_G(H)=Ad_H(H)$ is isomorphic to $GL(\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb{R}))$ and so is a **matrix** lie algebra, which I think should have finite center? [still, doesn't say anything about $H$ itself)

I don't mind references to books proving relevant propositions.

Comment: You're on the right track here, all that needs doing is proving that the derivative of the adjacency equals zero for the subgroup $ H \subseteq G $

Comment: @Cppg: Do you mean $[Ad(H),Ad(H)]=0$? Why is it enough? Doesn't it just show $Ad(H)$ is abelian?

Comment: $ \mathcal{D}G \sim g(n+1) - g(n) $, and similarly $ \mathcal{D}H \sim h(p+1) - h(p) $, so if $ p < n $ for $ \mathcal{D}G = 0 $, then $ \bar{H} \subseteq G $ thus $ H $ has a finite centre about $ n_{k} $.

Comment: @Cppg: I'm sorry, but most of the things here are unclear to me. I am probably lacking some context/basic knowledge in these derivatives. Any chance for some clarifications/relevant links?

Comment: Hint: Use the fact that the universal cover of $SL(2,R)$ is not isomorphic to any matrix group.

Comment: $ G := \{ g(1), g(2), g(3), ... g(n)\} $ , $ H := \{h(1), h(2), h(3) ... h(p)\} $, then a turning point in either of these sets would be attributed to a trivial first order derivative: $ dg(n) = g(n+1) - g(n) $. Thus if $ dg(n) = 0 $ before $ dh(p) = 0 $ for $ n,p \in \mathbb{N} $, then the closure of $ H $ is also a subset of $ G $, $\bar{H} \subseteq G $.Which analytically means that the supremum of $ H $ will never exceed $ G $ at such a turning point. Therefore $ H $ has a fixed centre around $ G $.

Comment: @MoisheCohen: I am having some hard time with this. I suppose you want me to assume $Z(H)$ is infinite and find an isomorphism $Ad(H)\to \tilde{SL(2,R)}$ as a contradiction. Since $Ad(H)=H/Z(H)$ it is enough to find a surjection $H\to \tilde{SL(2,R)}$ with kernel $Z(H)$. Isn't that precisely the universal covering map? Where does the size center even gets in here? Im missing something (perhaps easy)

Comment: @MoisheCohen: Wait, since $\mathfrak{h}$ is simple, and H is connected, the center (as a norm subgroup) must be discrete. Therefore any homomorphism with kernel $Z(H)$ is a covering map. Does this help me in this direction?

Comment: @Thewayoflife: Exactly: such $H$ would have to be an infinite connected cover of $PSL(2,R)$ and there is only one, which is ....

Comment: @MoisheCohen: The only infinite connected cover of $PSL(2,R)$ is the universal covering of $SL(2,R)$ I think. I also think I understand why $H$ can't be that group (cause the adjoint of a non-matrix group is a non-matrix group, despite the fact that $Ad(H)$ is a matrix group (correct?). But why would $H$ be a cover of $PSL(2,R)$ in the first place?

Comment: @Thewayoflife: Two locally isomorphic connected Lie groups $G_1, G_2$ always have isomorphic universal covers. (Take the universal covers of $G_1, G_2$: They are locally isomorphic and simply-connected, hence, isomorphic. This will be discussed in any decent textbook on the Lie theory)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The kernel of the map $\operatorname{Ad}\colon G \to GL(\mathfrak{g})$ is $Z(G)$ . The image of $H$ under this map ( let's call it $H_1$) is isomorphic to $SL(2, \mathbb{R})$ or $PSL(2,\mathbb{R})$ ( this because any linear representation of $sl(2, \mathbb{R})$ comes from a representation of $SL(2, \mathbb{R})$). Therefore we have a covering map 
$H \to H_1$ with kernel $Z(G) \cap H$ and this gives an exact sequence
$$0 \to Z(G) \cap H \to Z(H)\to Z(H_1) \to 0$$ and now the conclusion follows.

This holds more generally for $H$ semi simple, since $H_1$, a linear semisimple connected Lie group will have a finite center.

Comment: Thank you. Still need two clarifications: 1. Isn't the map $Z(H)\to Z(H_1)$ simply the zero map? as the adjoint of  a central element is the derivative of the identity which is zero? 2. I didn't quite get why the kernel is $Z(G)\cap H$ and not something perhaps larger - it is easier to be in $Z(H)$ than in $Z(G)$

Comment: @The way of life: We don't know apriori if $H_1$ itself is an adjoint group ( like $PSL(2,\mathbb{R})$)  or  larger ( like $SL(2, \mathbb{R})$). It may be that an adjoint group contains semisimple subgroups with non-trivial centers.  Now, about the kernel, it's what acts trivially on $\mathfrak{g}$, so trivially on $G$ ( $G$ connected), so it has to be in the center of $G$.

Comment: I get the part about the kernel now (an element of $H_1$ isn't an automorphism of $\mathfrak{h}$ but of $\mathfrak{g}$). This also makes the question abuot the map $Z(H)\to Z(H_1)$ okay. But one last question is why $Z(H)\to Z(H_1)$ **surjective**? in general, $\phi(Z(H))\subset Z(\phi (H))=Z(H_1)$ but couldn't it possiblt be a proper subset? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @The way of life: this is true for covering maps of connected Lie groups. If $h$ maps to an element in the center of $H_1$ then the image acts trivially on $\mathfrak{h}_1$. But then $h$ acts trivially on $\mathfrak{h}$ so it is in the center of $H$.  Of course it's not true for arbitrary morphisms of (Lie ) groups.